# Событие перехода в полноэкранный режим.WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gui

Стоит биндинг Grid на размеры окна, и года я постепенно увеличиваю окно, то все работает, а когда нажимаю на полное разворачивание(не знаю, как назвать - пусть будет полноэкранный режим), то Grid остается такой же. Что можно сделать?

Comment: А зачем вообще биндить размеры грида к окну? Его нужно просто "положить" в окно. Он сам прекрасно адаптируется под размеры родительского контейнера

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае его не надо привязывать, можно просто написать

```
HorizontalAlignment (/Vertical)

HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Пример : http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms751709.aspx

Там же рассказывается и про отступы `Margin`/`Padding`

И ещё: если грид просто перетянуть, то все значения сразу студия запишет сама- отступы справа/слева...ширину/длину

Если это всё (или некоторое) убрать в разметке, то грид(или др.элемент) будет растягиваться в ту или иную сторону.